# mongodb text search with multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get mongodb fulltext search with multiple fields working.
I've set the index on 3 fields-name,description, category, and verified with

`document.collection.getIndexes ()`, 
which returns-

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "document.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 2,
            "description" : 1,
            "category" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_2_description_1_category_1",
        "ns" : "document.collection",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
```

Now, if I try to perform a text search, using the follwing command-

```
db.collection.find(  {$text:{$search:'alias'}}  ).limit(10)
```

got the following error message:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=document.collection limit=10 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=alias, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query",
    "code" : 17007
}
```

I tried google and mongodb docs but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: That is not a text index. The name would have "text" after every field name and other indicators.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should create a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) on the fields you want to search:

```
db.deals.ensureIndex({ name: "text", description : "text", category : "text" });
```

From the documentation of the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator:

> $text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with
>   a text index.

The index you created for your three fields is a compound index, not a text index. The text index will look like this:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "name_text_description_text_category_text",
    "ns" : "test.deals",
    "weights" : {
        "category" : 1,
        "description" : 1,
        "name" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

Comment: I already have:
`db.deals.ensureIndex({name:"text"},{description:"text"},{category:"text"})`

Comment: Thanks, @Christian, can you tell me how to ensureIndex in mongoose?
I've used this line to create the index:

`Schema.index({name:2,description:1,category:1});`

Comment: @MukeshSoni you should probably ask that in a separate question. That way it can help others.

Comment: Since the question wasn't asked again, you can ensure index yourself with
`var model = mongoose.model('ModelName', Schema); model.collection.ensureIndex({name: 'text', description: 'text', category: 'text'}, function(error) {});`

Comment: How do you make a search on the indexes fields then? ie find documents with name="a" and description="b" etc.

Comment: Note:Deprecated since version 3.0.0: db.collection.ensureIndex() has been replaced by db.collection.createIndex().