# Not able to create index using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a search feature in a Node.js application which uses Mongoose, creating a full-text search index in Mongo:

```
postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        xx : String
        .......
    }).index({
          'xx':'text'
        });
    Post = mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
```

And execute the search as follows:

```
find = {'$text':{'$search':query}};
findScore = {'score':{'$meta':'textScore'}};
sort = {'score': {'$meta':'textScore'} };
Post.find(find, findScore).sort(sort).exec(function (err, data) {
          if (err){
            logging.log(err);
          } else {
            logging.log(data);
          }
                });
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:
'Unable to execute query: error processing query \n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb text search with multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257390/mongodb-text-search-with-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 1):

A collection can have at most one text index. You need to check it any of the text index is previously created.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, deleting previous index helped. Also, I had a field in my schema called language and it is a reserved keyword in Mongo because of which it was giving me an "Cannot override language error". Changing the field name worked.